# page source with $get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there something out there that will allow me to do something similar to:

```
<script>
var source;
sources = $.get("www.johnverber.com/?url=www.google.com");

document.write(source);
</script>
```

Obviously this code doesn't work...

Comment: [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Comment: Similar to what, the document.write part or the .get() part?

Comment: Who is the host? Are you trying to get johnverber.com from johnverber.com?

Comment: sorry.  no it was from a different website...say google.com

Comment: @Verber then nothing will work because most browser's cross-site security exception. You would need to create a local proxy which is another question. If you expose a JSONP API then you can send anything you want using `$.getJSON()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have many options when it comes to getting data from a different host. You will most likely run to the cross-domain errors. You should expose [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) web service. You could then do the following with [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON('http://www.johnverber.com/?url=www.johnverber.com/win1.html&callback=?', function(data){
  // do something with data
});
```

Note the `callback=?` query.

Comment: could I use this to set it to write with the data?  My end goal here is to throw the source code of a 'different' website into a txt file so I can parse it.

Comment: That's a big question. I assume you would get `url=www.johnverber.com ` parameter and return the HTML. But I don't know what you mean by writing the data to a text file? You can't write a text file using javascript.

Comment: Yeah it's kind  of a huge subject.  But I can view source programmically using window.location = viewsource: window.location + someURL;  I want to read what pops up in window.location which is just text...then somehow save it.  I can then parse it.  I assume I could do all of that with javascript, ajax, jquery, or some other language. If I can get a file on my server I can call perl scripts to parse...I just need to get it up on my server.